# How to get a dashed line on Y axis and how to display the value beside the graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I have written the following script to display bar charts.
But , I need to do three more things

```
1) Get a dashed line on Y-axis
2) Increase spacing between the graphs
3) Display Value beside the end of the bar graph
```

Here is my code below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>


.chart div {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
    var data = [ {
        "label" : "You ",
        "value" : 60
    }, {
        "label" : " Recommended",
        "value" : 60
    }, {
        "label" : "Peers",
        "value" : 40
    } ];
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(
            [ "#8BA870", "#000000", "#FF8040", "#ff8c00" ]);

    var barPad = 10;
//  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([ 0, d3.max(data)]).range([ 0, 420 ]);

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000]).range([0, 1000]);

    d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div")
    .style({stroke: "black", "stroke-width": "2px"})
    .style("height", function(d) { return 20+"px"; })
    .style("font-size","20px")
    .style("width", function(d) {
        return (d.value+100) + "px";
    }).style("background-color", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
    }).text(function(d, i) {
        return data[i].label;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: you can increase the spacing by increasing `margin` in your css class.
https://jsfiddle.net/xcy1qg0z/

Comment: Any idea about 1 and 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

for making the y axis

```
d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div").data(data).enter()
.append("div")
.style("width","1px")
.style("height",height*2 + "px")
.style("padding-top","0.1px")
.style("padding","0.1px")
.style("background-color","black")
```

for making bars

```
.append("div")
.style({stroke: "black", "stroke-width": "2px"})
.style("height", function(d) { return height+"px"; })
.style("font-size","20px")
.style("margin-top","10px")
.style("text-align","left")
.style("width", function(d) {
    return (d.value+100) + "px";
}).style("background-color", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
}).text(function(d, i) {
    return data[i].label;
})
```

For making text @ the end of bar:

```
.append("p")
.style("margin-top", function(d) {
    return -height -5 + "px";
})
.style("margin-left", function(d) {
    return (d.value+100) +10 + "px";
})

.style("color","black")
.text(function(d){ return d.value});
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/T907nrR3Gl72vCKFS8wU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Stroke width for dashed lines

```
svg.append("path")
       .datum(data1)
       .attr("class", "line blue")
       .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
       .attr("d", line1);
```

Comment: What is line1 here ?